# Green's Theorem and the Cauchy Integral Formula/Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

So we know by Green's Theorem that for $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $F = (P,Q)$, with $F$ defined on some open set $U$ such that $\partial U$ is piecewise smooth and simple (see JCT) that we have the relation:

$$
\iint_U \partial_xQ - \partial_yP \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{\partial U}
F \cdot T \mathrm{d}S$$

This formula is simply the two dimensional stokes theorem. When $F$ is treated as a map from $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, and $P,Q$ is replaced with $u,v$ (denoting the real, imaginary components of the function), we have an analogous result for functions of a complex variable. Specifically, we can write a complex line integral as:
$$
\int_\gamma f  (z) \mathrm{d}z = \int_{\gamma} [u(z) + iv(z)] (\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{id}y)
$$
Then, computing the product above allows us to apply Green's theorem, and the cauchy riemann equations (consequence of holomorphicness,we assume $f$ is holomorphic of course) lead to the double integrals being $0$. However, I am uneasy about this proof for a few reasons. First, where does the decompozition of the form $\mathrm{d}z$ come from? I have never studied complex valued forms/forms over the complex numbers, so maybe this the source of confusion for me. Is it simply the definition? I.e is $\mathrm{d}z$ a convention for $\mathrm{d}x + i \mathrm{d}y$?ARe the forms $dx,dy$ real valued or complex valued?

Comment: Think of it in terms of Riemann sums, and then take the limit. Your notation gives the correct result when interpreted as you have stated for integrals.

Comment: My complex analysis isn't very strong, but I believe that since we're dealing with holomorphic functions $dz$ could be equal to $\cos(\theta)dx+i\sin(\theta)dy$ for any $\theta$ (because the function will behave the same way no matter which direction you nudge it in). This is just my intuition though, someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we need to parametrize $ \gamma$ in

$$\int_\gamma f  (z) \mathrm{d}z = \int_{\gamma} [u(z) + iv(z)] (\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{id}y)$$

to get $$\gamma (t) =x(t)+i y(t)$$

The definition of complex integral is $$\int_\gamma f  (z) \mathrm{d}z = \int _{t_0}^{t_1} f(\gamma (t))\gamma ' (t) dt$$

Substituting the parametrization in $$\int_{\gamma} [u(z) + iv(z)] (\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{id}y)$$ will result in $$\int _{t_0}^{t_1} f(\gamma (t))\gamma ' (t) dt$$

Answer (score 0):

On the complex plane, we have two real coordinate functions and one complex coordinate function. The real coordinate functions are usually referred to as $x,y$, and accordingly, their differentials are $dx,dy$, respectively. Each of these differentials is a real-valued differential form, as the coordinate functions $x$ and $y$ are real-valued.

The complex coordinate function is given by $$z=x+iy,$$ and hence, its differential is $$dz=dx+idy.$$ This is, indeed, a complex-valued differential form.